# React Hooks `useState` set function exhibits sync as well as async behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider a button callback listener in React Functional components defined as below -

Here's the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-euler-1kp35s?file=/src/App.js:468-665) to repro this.

```js
const [setCtr, ctr] = useState(0);
const btnClicked = () => {
    console.log("button callback");
    setCtr((x) => {
      console.log("setCtr executed...");
      return x + 1;
    });
    console.log("button callback ends");
  };
```

When I click on the button, the first time, `setCtr` executes synchronously but after that it always (tried 20 times) runs asynchronously.

Here's the output for first button click

```
button callback 
setCtr executed... 
button callback ends
```

Here's the output for subsequent button clicks

```
button callback 
button callback ends 
setCtr executed... 

button callback 
button callback ends 
setCtr executed... 

button callback 
button callback ends 
setCtr executed... 

button callback 
button callback ends 
setCtr executed...
```

This is confusing. How exactly does the set function in `useState` work?
If it was truly an async function, we should always get `button callback ends` before `setCtr executed...`.
This makes me think sometimes it behaves as synchronous function, while sometimes as asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not totally true: *If it was truly an async function, we should always get button callback ends before setCtr executed....*
React 18 batches all setStates, but it has also a priority queue for every instruction that you write inside handlers, synchronous or asynchronous, so you should not rely on the callback of the setState to happen before or after something else, unless you explicitely say to React to execute it synchronously:

```js
function App() {
  const [ctr, setCtr] = React.useState(0);
  const btnClicked = () => {
    console.log("button callback", ctr);
    ReactDOM.flushSync(() =>
      setCtr((x) => {
        console.log("setCtr executed...",x);
        return x + 1;
      })
    );
    console.log("button callback ends", ctr);
  };
  console.log("RERENDERING X:", ctr)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {ctr}
      <br />
      <button onClick={btnClicked}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, root)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

React, especially React 18 applies some heavy code optimizations so don't think it just executes the code you write inside handlers "as is".
As you can see, using `flushSync` explicitely tells React to flush all the setStates immediately when invoked, so it stops all synchronous code inside the handler, re-renders the component, and then keeps executing the rest of the code. You can note, that the state of the last `log` is stale when it gets executed, and it refers to the previous value, since the instruction was memoized on the value of the state at the time you declared it. That's another important feature of React. That's why you should always rely on Hooks like `useEffect` or `useMemo` with the deps that you are interested to track, to perform operations after the state updated.

*Reference:* https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#flushsync

Comment: I am using React 17, and not 18.    
 
When you said `but it has also a priority queue for every instruction that you write inside handlers`, are you saying the handler function body is split into multiple statements, and each has a priority queue?    In our example, the first `console.log` then `setCtr call` and the last `console.log` statements are considered as separate instructions by React and it decides the order in which it should execute them? I am sorry but that sounds weird. Could you please explain with a little more clarity? Your example really helped in learning something new.

Comment: Take that statement with a grain of salt, I have not a deep enough knowledge of React source code to be able to confirm that, but React Fiber core engine does a lot of optimiziations of that kind, so I would not be surprised of that: https://applikeysolutions.com/blog/what-is-react-fiber-description-of-react-s-new-core-algorithm . The `setStates` are definitely considered as separae instructions, they are always  asynchronous unless you call them with `flushSync`, even in your example,  the fact the log inside the callback is executed synchronously doesn't mean the setState is sync.

Comment: The effective state setting and consequent re-render is executed asynchronously . What's sure is that Fiber algorithms are not easily predictable, that's why you should always rely on `effects` to perform sideEffects in response to a state change. More info on Fiber: https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/react-fiber-algorithm